# Running response time tests on php code - how much is 7.2E-5 microseconds?

Tags: php, load-testing, response-time

Hi guys I'm using microtime() function of php to tell how long certain snippets of code take to run I do this by taking the time before and after the snippet and subtracting them using microtime function.

I got the following results though for the different snippets:

```
1 -  0.022976

2 -  0.003656

3 - -0.196361

4-   0.006563

5-   7.2E-5

6-   0.847695

7-   0.005092

8-   7.6E-5

9-   0.08024
```

The first numbers represent the snippt and the following the time taken... I've forgotten whatever I learnt back in College on numerical methods :( - how big is 7.2E-5 microseconds?

Comment: It's fast.  But not as fast as that negative time you got.

Comment: What negative time? I mean which is the slowest to the highest - from the values given above which ones are troublesome?

Comment: Well, according to your results, #5 is the fastest, followed closely by #8.  But that's after excluding #3, which apparently finished before it started.

Comment: microtime() returns the microseconds part using 'seconds' as the unit rather than 'microseconds'.  This is slightly misleading.  Your actual question should be how big is 7.2E-5 seconds.

Comment: To avoid this kind of problem, when I'm benchmarking something this fast, I do it in a large loop that takes about a second or less total.

Answer (score 2):

7.2E-5 = 7.2 x 10^-5 = 7.2 x 0.00001 = 0.000072

So 7.2E-5 microseconds = 0.000072 microseconds